# Upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to update Laravel to the latest version 5.3.

I'm checking the [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0), but I don't see how to actually upgrade the code through composer.

When I try to update composer.json file to point to `laravel/framework` 5.3.*.

I get:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.4 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.1 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.3 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.2.4 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.44], illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.2.44].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
```

How should I update?

Comment: it is better if you can download the laravel 5.3 version files and  start your project with runnng the the given composer.json file. Isn't it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to update the LaravelCollective [html package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) as well.

In your `composer.json`, replace:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

with:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
```

(don't forget the trailing comma if there is one)